# Get access to USB device on Linux (libusb-1.0)?

Tags: linux, usb, libusb-1.0

I am writing a small program to communicate with a specific USB HID product (identified by vendor and product IDs), using libusb-1.0 on Linux.  Right now, I have to run the program as root because "libusb requires write access to USB device nodes".  Is there a way to change the permissions on the device I need so that I don't need to run my program as root?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On modern Linux systems, `udevd` (`man 7 udev`) creates the device nodes for USB devices when they're plugged in.  Add a udev rule that matches your device (eg. you could match by USB Vendor and Product IDs), and sets the `OWNER` / `GROUP` / `MODE` of the device node.

The best approach is probably to create a new group for users who should be able to access the device, then set that as the group owner in the udev rule.  You may also need to use `MODE` to ensure that it has group read/write permissions.  Eg. your rule will probably look something like:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="ffee", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5a5a", MODE="0660", GROUP="foobar"
```

Comment: This didn't work on me until I added quotation marks around "0660"

Comment: Concur with the above comment. Quotes required around the "0660" for this to work. I submitted an edit to the original answer but, alas, it was rejected as being too minor :/

Comment: @phil-lavin: I don't know why your change was rejected, but I've applied it anyway.